# There is no New -> Android Project

Tags: android, adt

I have downloaded ADT Bundle Windows. Installed it and configured it.

There are these options:

- Android Application Project
- Android Project from Existing Code
- Android Sample Project
- Android Test Project

I just started reading *Head First Android Development* and none of the above didn't open what it says in book.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The development tools change more frequently than do most books.

What had been "Android Project" is now "Android Application Project".

There will be many more differences between what that book describes and what you see, as that book is nearly two years old, and the tools have changed since then.

Comment: man... I feel sorry for the OP. If they cant work this out they are going to struggle

Answer (score 0):

The wording will change as the program evolves and gets updated. You are probably using an outdated book. What you are looking for is the *Android Application Project*.

Answer (score 0):

Android application Project is the new name for it. If you want to create an android library project there is a checkbox in the setup wizard that will allow you to do it.